# Rails SQLite3 duplicate column - Treehouse Tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, devise

I've just started a Treehouse tutorial working on a Simple Ruby App. To give context, I previously had to delete and start over on this project, which I deleted the main app folder and started over.

Following the tutorial we've created a User database which includes all Devise included tables (:email, :name, etc). The error that I'm getting states that I have a duplicated column name. After reviewing and tinkering I tried to comment out the problem column to see if things will move forward in my migration but it just gives the same error for the next line.

A few times I've tried to drop the database, re-create and re-migrate but I'm getting the same issue.

Ideally I'd like to just remove the databases and recreate them, but that doesn't seem like something I can do.

Here is the error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: email: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "email" varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL
/Users/pbj/Desktop/code/rails/treebook/db/migrate/20121130035155_add_devise_to_users.rb:5:in `block in up'
/Users/pbj/Desktop/code/rails/treebook/db/migrate/20121130035155_add_devise_to_users.rb:3:in `up'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

When I generated the User set from Devise it also gave me the create_status.rb, devise_create_user.rb and add_devise_to_users.rb (which is the problematic file). The thought of removing Devise and starting over crossed my mind, but I've already done that which has brought me to this new error.

Apologize if this is somewhat rudimentary for all the experience programmers, but as mentioned above, I'm learning but just got off of the original path of this tutorial.

Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think despite of your `db/migrate/0000-00000_create_user.rb` you have added another `add_email_to_users` migration to your model. So check your `create_user.rb` in db/migration folder and see if email column is already there, then check for other migration file such as `add_email_to_users.rb` in db/migrate folder, if you found such an extra `add_email migration` then delete it.

At the end rename/delete your `development.sqlite3` file and try to `rake db:migrate` from scratch.

this might help you solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking the same course and I think the error lies that Ruby 4 just came out and it has a duplicated line on the migrate directory,  I deleted and then ran rake db:migrate.  It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Your error message said this:

```
duplicate column name: email: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "email" varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL
```

Your migration file (some random number then...)_add_devise_to_users.rb is adding these lines which you should now comment out

```
# t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""

# add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
```

This will allow you to now migrate with this command

```
rake db:migrate
```

If you are still struggling and don't mind destroying and recreating the database you can do this to start fresh

```
rake db:drop db:create db:migrate
```

Hope this helps!